# Jaynes probability Exercise 3.3 (maximum-entropy)

Tags: probability-theory, combinations, information-theory, entropy

**Exercise 3.3**
Suppose that in the previous exercise k is initially unknown, but we know that the urn contains exactly 50 balls. Drawing out 20 of them, we find three different colors; now what do we know about k? We know from deductive reasoning (i.e. with certainty) that 3 ≤ k ≤ 33; but can you set narrower limits k1 ≤ k ≤ k2 within which it is highly likely to be?
( Hint: This question goes beyond the sampling theory of this chapter because, like most real scientific problems, the answer depends to some degree on our common sense judgments; nevertheless, our rules of probability theory are quite capable of dealing with it, and persons with reasonable common sense cannot differ appreciably in their conclusions.)

I guess the most likely answer is $ k = 3 $.
We can solve this problem by iterating $3 \le k \le 33$, within each situation, this may use the maximum entropy to get the most likely distribution and then we can compute the maximum probability to get 3 kinds of colors.
Through this method, We will get an optimized k.
Am i right, help, Thank you.

Comment: This is a great exercise, but your question is missing the actual definition of the urn, and the hint "this question goes beyond the sampling theory of this Chapter because, like most real scientific problems, the answer depends to some degree on our common sense judgments; nevertheless our rules of probability theory are quite capable of dealing with it, and persons with reasonable common sense cannot differ appreciably in their conclusions"

Comment: Yes. and  I will append it.